# Flutter App's Scene Delegate, How to modify

Tags: flutter, flutter-method-channel

I'm developing a Flutter App, and i need to write some native code to implement a third party sdk.
SDK's documentation says i need to use app's navigation controller to initialize sdk. I need to give the app's navigation controller to a method as parameter. In documentation, they give an example about this, they have write the code inside the SceneDelegate file. But in my app, there's no SceneDelegate file. What happens if i put this code inside AppDelegate?
How can I use navigation controller inside app delegate?
Do I need to create a SceneDelegate?